# Java: Render video with extra box on it.

Tags: java, opencv, video, video-processing

I have got a mpg video file from a camera and I'd like to import this file to java application which should do some things on it and save new video file with apply all operation.

What I want to do exactly:

Below is a sample frame from my video.

[image: Simple frame from sample video]

And after imported video, java app should add some content at the bottom of video(for each frame) like fps, date etc. I know that this information can be extracted by openCv, but it's not my problem. I don't know how to make such a content and add it to a video and render to external mpg file. I prepare a simple demonstration how should look the output video after render by my app.

[image]

Comment: [putText](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#putText(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.lang.String,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20int,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar)) to start with

Comment: Maybe start with the tutorial of OpenCV and Java: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html. Then take a look at the videoWriter and videoCapture classes and as @berak mentions putText